# Equivalent query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Following is the query written in ORACLE to give previous row , output given at last.
How to frame below ORACLE query in MS Access specially ROWNUM part.. Appreciate your inputs

```
orcl> WITH d
  2       AS (SELECT ROWNUM rn,
  3                  dname,
  4                  deptno
  5           FROM   (SELECT dname,
  6                          deptno
  7                   FROM   dept
  8                   ORDER  BY dname)),
  9       e
 10       AS (SELECT ROWNUM + 1 rn,
 11                  dname,
 12                  deptno
 13           FROM   (SELECT dname,
 14                          deptno
 15                   FROM   dept
 16                   ORDER  BY dname))
 17  SELECT rn,
 18         d.dname,
 19         d.deptno this_row,
 20         e.deptno previous_row
 21  FROM   d
 22         left outer join e USING (rn)
 23  ORDER  BY dname;

    RN DNAME            THIS_ROW      previous_ROW
```

---

```
     1 ACCOUNTING             10
     2 OPERATIONS             40           10
     3 RESEARCH               20           40
     4 SALES                  30           20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access SQL doesn't have direct counterparts for some of those Oracle features your query uses, so you can't "*translate*" it to Access.  Instead you'll have to rewrite it from scratch.

You can use a `DMax()` expression to return the "previous" `dname`.

```
SELECT
    dname,
    deptno AS this_row,
    DMax("dname", "dept", "dname < '" & [dname] & "'")
        AS previous_dname
FROM dept;
```

That query returns this result set:

```
dname       this_row previous_dname
ACCOUNTING        10
OPERATIONS        40 ACCOUNTING
RESEARCH          20 OPERATIONS
SALES             30 RESEARCH
```

Then left join that result set back to the `dept` table, with the join based on `previous_dname = dname`.

```
SELECT
    d1.dname,
    d1.this_row,
    d2.deptno AS previous_row
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            dname,
            deptno AS this_row,
            DMax("dname", "dept", "dname < '" & [dname] & "'")
                AS previous_dname
        FROM dept
    ) AS d1
    LEFT JOIN dept AS d2
    ON d1.previous_dname = d2.dname
ORDER BY d1.dname;
```

I left out the `rn` (ROWNUM) column since it isn't needed for the join with this approach.  However, if you still need/want it for some other reason, you can derive it with a `DCount()` expression.

```
SELECT
    d1.rn
    d1.dname,
    d1.this_row,
    d2.deptno AS previous_row
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DCount("*", "dept", "dname <= '" & [dname] & "'")
                AS rn
            dname,
            deptno AS this_row,
            DMax("dname", "dept", "dname < '" & [dname] & "'")
                AS previous_dname
        FROM dept
    ) AS d1
    LEFT JOIN dept AS d2
    ON d1.previous_dname = d2.dname
ORDER BY d1.dname;
```

Comment: Thanks so Much... But would it possible with this approach to get previous value which asked in question at below link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001873/previous-record-ms-access

Comment: What exactly this DMax function syntax doing here with text data

Comment: That `DMax()` expression evaluates all the `dname` values which are "less than" the current `dname` value, and returns the "greatest" of those.  Just as A < B and B < C, so is ACCOUNTING < OPERATIONS and so on.

Comment: Thanks HansUp..Do you think is this efficient approach in addressing requirement asked at stackoverflow.com/questions/12001873/previous-record-ms-access

Comment: say column name is with space like "Client ID" then is this correct syntax DMax("[Client ID]", "dept", "[Client ID] < '" & [Client ID] & "'")

Comment: also say I have Date column as well..will this syntax work for date comparison as well? I am getting #error with this