# Ms Access Combine Two Rows into one like this

Tags: ms-access

I need with MS Access Combine two rows with the same id and same date into one row like this if TimeCome > 12:01 PM

Multi Row Picture

[image]

to be

One Row Picture

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the work you have done so far?

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tables can be shown as formated text, read tags description before use. Get familiar with "database normalization", that's the first step in ms-access. People can't leave and arrive twice or more a day and stay over midnight? Just 2 problems that get solved by normalization.

Comment: Rats! How can copy/paste go so bad!! Should have been this link in my flag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001873/previous-record-ms-access. Now I can't change flag, just delete comment with bad reference. Wonder how the flag got approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Select 
    ID, DateCome, UserName, Min(TimeCom) As TimeCome, Max(TimeCom) As TimeLeave
From
    YourTable
Group By
    ID, DateCome, UserName
```

Comment: Thank you Soooo Much   " Gustav " 
You r amazing